Only default values are fetched by another service in Angular
I am trying to follow a tutorial in angular.
Issue #1:
Issue occurs while using 2 services namely recipe.service.ts (handles data manipulation locally) and data-storage.service.ts (stores data in firebase). When the getRecipes() method is called from the data-storage.service.ts only the default values are returned not the updated one.
Image for better clarification. Browser Dev Tools Console
The point where the Save Data button is clicked is marked in red in above image.
Issue #2:
The instructor uses this.recipes.slice() without any parameter to fetch data, however if I use it the newly added or deleted values are not reflected. In order to view the changes I used this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length). My question is if the length changes what is the correct way to get it reflected.
contents of recipe.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { Ingredient } from '../shared/ingredient.model';
import { ShoppingListService } from '../shopping-list/shopping-list.service';

@Injectable()
export class RecipeService {
  recipesChanged = new Subject<Recipe[]>();

  // private recipes: Recipe[] = [];
  private recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe(
      'Tasty Schnitzel',
      'A super-tasty Schnitzel - just awesome!',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/72/Schnitzel.JPG',
      [
        new Ingredient('Meat', 1),
        new Ingredient('French Fries', 20)
      ]),
    new Recipe('Big Fat Burger',
      'What else you need to say?',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Burger_King_Angus_Bacon_%26_Cheese_Steak_Burger.jpg',
      [
        new Ingredient('Buns', 2),
        new Ingredient('Meat', 1)
      ])
  ];

  constructor(private slService: ShoppingListService) {}

  setRecipes(recipes: Recipe[])
  {
    this.recipes = recipes;     
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
    console.log('setRecipes');
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
  }

  getRecipes() 
  {
    console.log('getRecipes');
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length)); 
    return this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length);
  }

  getRecipe(index: number) 
  {
    console.log('getRecipe'); 
    return this.recipes[index];
  }

  addIngredientsToShoppingList(ingredients: Ingredient[]) 
  {
     
    this.slService.addIngredients(ingredients);
    console.log('addIngredientsToShoppingList');
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
  }

  addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) 
  {    
    this.recipes.push(recipe);
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
    console.log('addRecipe');
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
  }

  updateRecipe(index: number, newRecipe: Recipe) 
  {
    
    this.recipes[index] = newRecipe;
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
    console.log('updateRecipe'); 
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
  }

  deleteRecipe(index: number) 
  {
     
    this.recipes.splice(index, 1);       
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
    console.log('deleteRecipe');
    console.log(this.recipes.slice(0,this.recipes.length));
  }
}

contents of data-storage.service.ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RecipeService } from "../recipes/recipe.service";
import { Recipe } from "../recipes/recipe.model";
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DataStorageService 
{
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private recipeService: RecipeService)
    {

    }

    storeRecipes()
    {
        const recipes = this.recipeService.getRecipes();
        console.log('storeRecipes');
        console.log(recipes);
        // this.http.put('https://....../recipes.json', recipes)
        // .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    }

    fetchRecipes()
    {
        return this.http
        .get<Recipe[]>(
          'https://....../recipes.json'
        )
        .pipe(
          map(recipes => {
            return recipes.map(recipe => {
              return { ...recipe, ingredients: recipe.ingredients ? recipe.ingredients : [] };
            });
          }),
          tap(recipes => {
            this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
          })
        )
    }
}


Thanks in advance.
I was expecting data-storage.service.ts to get the updated values from recipe.service.ts. Is any separate object is getting created by any of my mistake?

UPDATE
The problem lies in the creation of two instances of RecipeService

In the app.module.ts There is an instance of recipe service, which is the correct place where it should be defined, since it needs to be at the same level as data service.

The problem was due to the second instance created when RecipeService was added to the providers array of recipes.component.ts, this created a second instance, which got updated with all the latest values, but is not visible to data service since DI took the component instance instead of the module instance


recipes.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';
import { RecipeService } from './recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  templateUrl: './recipes.component.html',
  styleUrl: './recipes.component.css',
  // providers: [RecipeService] // <- this created a separate instance and removing it fixed the issue!
})
export class RecipesComponent implements OnInit {
...

Stackblitz Demo (might not work due to commit issues)

Arrays are stored as references in memory not the actual values.
When you push or delete any element from the array, try updating the array reference using "array de-structuring" so that the new reference has the latest element inside it, might fix your issue:
addRecipe(recipe: Recipe) 
  {    
    this.recipes.push(recipe);
    this.recipes = [...this.recipes];  // <- changed here!        
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes);
    console.log('addRecipe');
    console.log(this.recipes);
  } 

  deleteRecipe(index: number) 
  {
     
    this.recipes.splice(index, 1);       
    this.recipes = [...this.recipes];  // <- changed here!
    this.recipesChanged.next(this.recipes);
    console.log('deleteRecipe');
    console.log(this.recipes);
  }


Hi, I tried your suggested method, however the issue remains. data-storage.service.ts does not get the updated values from recipe.service.ts when getRecipes() method is called.

Please refer to the link

@DipayanRay stackblitz reference
